# How to do single flight in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have API to get data and it took 10 seconds to get a response. If multiple requests with same parameter come in at the same time, how to make process just for first request, and then after process finish, the result will be distributed for all request? In golang, I can do it very easy using single flight.

Comment: You mean caching the result? Or you can make a `var res; if (res !== null) return res; else heavyCompute(res))`

Comment: No, not caching result. I mean there is no duplicate same process in the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on this would be to hash the parameters, and use an object of promises, with the hash as key.

It would go like this :

1. A request with some parameters comes in.
2. You hash the parameters in the way you want.
3. You check the object for any value associated to the hash.
4. **If the value does not exists**, you create a new promise, and store it in the object.
5. And in all cases you return the promise from the object.

Don't forget to delete the value from the object when the associated promise resolves, so the next requests starts a new query.